# Loading PDF into UIWebView - Anything faster?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I'm doing an application, which loads PDFs from an URL, but is there anything better then using UIWebView? Or any way of loading it page-by-page instead of loading the whole file at once?

I mean it does the job, but it takes **30seconds - 3 minutes** to load a PDF on an **iPhone 5** while standing **NEXT** to the router...

I can't imagine what would happen when I ran this code on an iPhone 4 with crappy internet...

Code which does the loading:

```
CatalogsWebViewController *webViewController = [[CatalogsWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CatalogsWebView" bundle:nil];
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://%@.s3.amazonaws.com/%@",kAmazonAWSBucketName,[catalogs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
webViewController.pdfRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

//Here self is webViewController, which got pushed into the navigation controller.
[self.webView loadRequest:self.pdfRequest];
```

Hum... it turns out, it's not due to the webView, it's cause it takes an immense time to download the file from the S3 bucket. When loading it from [NSBundle mainBundle], it does it it seconds.

Comment: i don't think its possible with the webview...so export the PDF into multiple pages and put it on ur server..and create multiple webviews for different pdf pages...and load it as u said,one by one...

Comment: http://pspdfkit.com..... good luck

Comment: I don't think they have 5K USD to throw out the window...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the problem comes from network connectivity, you should display a loading bar while downloading the PDF so the user understands what is going on. Then, upon download completion, save the PDF in the documents folder of your app if the user wants to reopen it later

Comment: Yeah, once I realized it due to the download time, there was no point of this question.